# Where can I find a Chinese corpus concordance?

Tags: academic

[Compleat Lexical Tutor](http://www.lextutor.ca/) has a valuable tool [here](http://www.lextutor.ca/concordancers/concord_e.html)<sup>1</sup> for searching for English words in a corpus and displaying them in sample sentences. This is useful for checking the usage of a word. Where can I find a similar tool for Chinese?

---

<sup>1. The links path to get to the page is the following: Compleat Lexical Tutor —> Concordances —> English.</sup>

Comment: "Concorance" isn't an English word, what did you mean to write? By the way, you wrote "Cinese" instead of "Chinese".

Comment: I added a note, so in case the link has some problems, they still can get to the page. :) Anyway, in the future, avoid writing "here" or "this" in text-links, better to write the title of the page/document you're linking or an explanation of what people can find in that link. So if the link gets unavailable or has problems, they can still get to the original link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which website/service can give good example sentences in Chinese?](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/647/which-website-service-can-give-good-example-sentences-in-chinese)

Answer (score 1):

Though it is much smaller than the corpus you linked to, [JuKuu](http://www.jukuu.com/) is an excellent resource for finding example sentences involving Chinese terms. Typing a Chinese word or phrase into the search bar usually yields enough sentences to get a good sense of a term's meaning and usage.

Comment: Oh I even saw this site before, someone linked it elsewhere. +1 by the way. :)